# MS Excel - Get multiple results based on same values in a column

Tags: excel

Basically my problem is that I have an integer (`1`) in one cell in excel, and I want to show all the rows from an another worksheet, where the first column has the same integer (`1`).

Example of Worksheet 2

```
Slot         Data1     Data2
1            15        124
2            20        23
1            89        523
3            20        23
```

Now I want to scan the Slot column for `1` and then populate the cells with the values under Data1.

I have tried to work with functions INDEX and MATCH, but the problem is it gives back only the first row where the Slot column has `1`

My function is: `=INDEX('Worksheet2'!DATA1:DATA1;(MATCH(1;'Worksheet2'!SLOT:SLOT)))`

This function search in Worksheet 2's SLOT column for the integer `1` and gives back the value of DATA1 from the same row.
In this case we've got back 15 as result. The only problem is, this function only finds the first row with the value 1 in SLOT's column, but I want to get back all of the rows having `1` as SLOT.

How can I get 15 also 89 as result - maybe in another cell in Worksheet 1? Do I need to use VBA on this?

(I'm using Excel 2013)

Comment: @pnuts The problem is more complex, only I don't know how to do this part working. Because of the whole problem, the output will be only one cell, also I could try to filter them by the SLOT column, but then I'd have to have lots of subpanels to do it working, becuase there are like 300 slots from where it needs to choose. Asking your answer, simply neither of them suits my needs. Sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to transcribe this to your named ranges with worksheet scope.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DATA1, SMALL(INDEX(ROW(SLOT)+(SLOT<>1)*1E+99, , ), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

Fill down for the second, third, etc. matches.